# How to compare two tar files in terms of the packaging ,signing , obfuscation mechanism i?

Tags: linux, ant, jar, keytool

I have two tar files(containing many jar files and jnlps) . I need to find out the differences between the two tar file in terms of the signing method , Sealing method and Obfuscation technique if any applied on the jar file contained in the tar.

Comment: can you extract tar contents to a temporary directory?

Comment: yes i can extract the content . I am going through the ant build file where the commands of signing , sealing etc is given . But there are so many linked build file , i am finding it very difficult to search it in them .

Comment: So i thought of comparing the two tars . Is there any method by which i can see these differences?

Comment: I'm not a java expert, but I guess having jar files in tar archives adds some complexity. Just leave jar files in separate directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a jar is signed, two additional files are included in the jar's META-INF directory. See the [documentation for jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html). You can learn whether a jar is signed, and what file was used to sign it, by checking the content of the META-INF directory.

When a jar is sealed, there will be additional content in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. See the [tutorial on package sealing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html). You can check how a jar is sealed by checking the content of that file.

Regarding obfuscation, I have no idea.

You could write a script which does something like this:

```
extract the tar
find all jars
for each jar
# signing info
list META-INF/*.SF and META-INF/*.DSA
# sealing info
search META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for line pairs matching "Name: xxx<newline>Sealed: true"
```

Write your output to a file.
Compare the output of your script for the two different tar files.

(But really, you probably need to spend more time to understand your build files.)